# Gson Deserilize Map<String, List<SomeType>>

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit with Gson for my android application And I have two class:

```
SomeClass1{

private Map<String, String> someMap;
private String otherProperty1;
private String otherProperty2;

}


SomeClass2{

  private Map<String, Object> someMap;
  private String otherProperty;
}
```

I have JsonDeserializer for `<Map<String, Object>>`:

```
@Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();     

        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterable<Entry<String,JsonElement>> entries = jsonObject.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), Object.class) );
        }

        return result;      
    }
```

The problem is:

When I get SomeClass2 object from json, where `someMap` contains `<String, SomeClass1>` , It's working perfect, but if `someMap` contains `<String, List<SomeClass1>>`  It gives me array of LinkedMapTree instead of Array of SomeClass1. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: If Retrofit mapped everything into "Object" for me, I would cry. Is the Rest API really that undefined?

Comment: You can specify expected type and gson works with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
result.put(entry.getKey(), gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), List.class) );
```